# SSAS is deploying to a new cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

When I update my SSAS cube and deploy it, all changes are deployed to a new cube on Analysis services database

[image]

deploying process is supposed to replace any pre-existing database with the contents of the project deployed.
So why it is not deploying in the right cube and instead it is creating a new one with the same *name_username_reference* ? how can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 4):

That's your workspace database, which includes your username followed by a GUID in the database name.  To ensure that you're deploying the correct Tabular model, from SSDT right-click on your SSAS project, in the Deployment pane (under Configuration Properties) verify that the correct database name has been entered in the Database field in the Deployment Server section.

Comment: Adding to this, you can instruct SSDT to detach the workspace database after you close SSDT. To do this, set the [Workspace Retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/workspace-database-ssas-tabular?view=sql-server-2017#bkmk_ws_prop) option to "Unload from memory".